# How to find a .peg file on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos

I found this problem showing up on El Capitan Photos.

[image]

Does anybody know how to find the .peg file?

Additionally, I think this error is related to why some of my photos are not being imported into Photos. Has anybody else experienced the same problem?

Comment: I don't think he'll be able to change the photo if he can't find it. His post asks how to find it. Suggesting that he change it before he finds it won't get him far. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think, but I am not sure that **.PEG** files on iPhone is the container for **Google Snapseed** when you **save a modified image** and want to preserve original to make modifications (**non deterioring editing**).

Comment: I believe you're right. Here's a link to a discussion about these .peg files on Snapseed's forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/snapseed/GL_UUhRByQQ

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you should rename it to .jpg and then try again.